# CPU usage is extremly high due to mysql process

Tags: cpu-usage, mysql-error-1064

I have a godaddy VPS box with 4 GB RAM. It has only 1 website hosted with nearly 800-1000k hits perday. upon investigation i found that my cpu usage is some times goes above 100%. The below mysql process is the culprit. [image: cpu-high-usage]

Can some one help me. I have tried increasing open file limits but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable page support for the VPS instance:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/large-page-support.html